# How to continue row numbering each page in pagination using SQL Server and PHP (foreach method)

Tags: php

I'm trying to add row numbering for data shown, but when i try to go to the next page, the row number is reverting back from 1.

I want the row number is continuously added within the page number like if :

`The first page is showing 20 data, the row number is showing 1 ~ 20.`

`The second page is showing 20 data, the row number is showing 21 ~ 40, not 1 ~ 20`

How to handle it ?

This is my getPage function :

```
<?php
  function getPage($stmt, $pageNum, $rowsPerPage)
  {
   $offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
   $rows = array();
   $i = 0;
      while(($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC, SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE, $offset + $i)) && $i < $rowsPerPage)
      {
         array_push($rows, $row);
         $i++;
      }
    return $rows;
  }
```

This is my script :

```
 // Display the selected page of data.
 $pageNum = isset($_GET['pageNum']) ? $_GET['pageNum'] : 1;
 $page = getPage($stmt, $pageNum, $rowsPerPage);
 $i = $offset + 1;
   foreach($page as $row)
     echo "<tr>
             <td class='text-center'>".$i++."</td>
             <td class='text-center'>".$row[0]."</td>
             <td class='text-center'>$row[1]</td>
             <td class='text-center'>$row[2]</td>
             <td>$row[3]</td>
             <td>$row[7]</td>
             <td>$row[8]</td>
             <td>$row[4]</td>
             <td>$row[5]</td>
             <td>$row[6]</td>
             <td class='text-center'><a href='form-edit-laporan-pelanggar?id=".$row[0]."'><button class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'>Edit</button></a></td>
             <td class='text-center'><a data-href='delete?id=".$row[0]."' data-target='#delete' data-toggle='modal'><button class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'>Del</button></a></td>
           </tr>";


  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Where is your exact problem? Try using the SQL servers LIMIT to select just the data you are looking for and you are done :)

Comment: Unfortunately, i already browse for that method, but everything's shows me that SQL server doesn't recognize LIMIT function sir.. Unlike MySQL database, i can't just add limit function and get the row number output continued from the last number of rows in the last loaded page. :(

Comment: Okay, if you are using a SQL server without limit, you can fetch all rows and use [array_slice()](http://php.net/array_slice) on the resulting array

Comment: `$offset` is defined INSIDE the getPage function and thus not available in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the answer after unknown hours spend on thinking mode..
Just adding a magic script i create by logic and voila~ it works ! LOL~ xD

Here is the working script :

```
$mulai = ($pageNum>1) ? ($pageNum * $rowsPerPage) - $rowsPerPage : 0;

$i = $mulai + 1;
```

Just add and edit the variable from this script before the foreach statement.

Comment: that is correct answer